# World Cup Draw - Permutations

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Imagine there are 4 pots (Pots 1, 2, 3, & 4), each with 8 unique items. Suppose we then draw from those pots into 8 new groups, in the following way:

1. Draw from Pot 1 and place each item in a different group
2. Draw from Pot 2 and place in a new group (each group now has 2 items)
3. Draw from Pot 3 and place in a new group (each group now has 3 items)
4. Draw from Pot 4 and place in a new group (each group now has 4 items)

With this ordered draw, I'm struggling to come up with the number of permutations. My thoughts so far are:

- There are 8! = 40320 ways to arrange the 8 items from Pot 1
- But once you layer in Pots 2,3,4 does the number of permutations expand to (40320)^4? Or just 40320*4?

(This question is basically an abstract version of how groups are drawn in the FIFA World Cup, soccer, and is what inspired my question)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

(40320)^4. This is because drawing from Pot $i$ is an action different from drawing from Pot $j$, and both are required to complete the task at hand. I couldn't draw from Pot $i$ and say that I am done drawing from Pot $j$. ($j \ne i$).

In other words, you have to draw from Pot $i$ $\textit{and}$ Pot $j$. This is different from drawing from Pot $i$ $\textit{or}$ Pot $j$.

Comment: This would be the answer if all the groups were labeled and considered different.  I don't think that's the intention, because it wouldn't be meaningful for World Cup groupings.  All that matters is which teams wind up together in each group, but not what the groups happen to be named.